# How to add border radius to css grid element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]
https://codepen.io/siddagra/pen/vYBoJyM 
I want to add border-radius to each of the five purple+grey boxes, Ideally not adding any html styles as the arrangement of div elements within the boxes itself may be subject to change. Please help, I tried: first-child and second-child selectors but that did not work.

```css
.ExpandedSetPiece:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.ExpandedSetPiece:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @LGSon , your'right ;)

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz i do not know who voted down, i see no reason when an answer works. When i downvote,  i usually explain cause i know how frustrating it can be, but, hey, it's only a website and doesn't make you any better or worse ;)

Comment: Well, thanks to you and @G-Cyr, my reputation went down. Why? Because I answered correctly and and helped someone... Thanks guys, you are the best developers..

Comment: I got 2 down votes? Even I answered correctly? I am sorry that I dont have 60k+ reps. Anyways, I wish you good luck..

Comment: it 's about time to clean the comment section, is not it ?

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz I only gave u upvotes, but it comes up at 0 upvotes here, it's probably just a bug in stackoverflow counting the upvotes, hopefully it gets fixed eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ExpandedSetPiece div:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.ExpandedSetPiece div:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

The term "child" is maybe a bit misleading. If you use `:first-child` on `.ExpandedSetPiece` it would mean the first of those groups.

Comment: styled the first element well, but not the last one, any tips/ideas? Thanks a lot btw :)

Comment: remove div and make a space between `.ExpandedSetPiece` and `:last-child`.

Comment: damn wtf? why does that work? and why does the other stuff not work? I'm very confused.. Thanks a lot though this solves my issue :)

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal `.ExpandedSetPiece {overflow:hidden}` works fine, remenber backgrounds are set on the children, not the box itself

Comment: `:first-child` is applied to the element, selecting only elements where the element is the first-child of its parent. So you need to add a space between them. That's how pseudo-selectors works.

Comment: right that would work too thnx, I guess that may be a better approach, still confused about why.ExpandedSetPiece:last-child doesn't but .ExpandedSetPiece :last-child does some weird stuff. never seen that notation with a space, maybe that's why my last-child and first-child selectors never work.

Comment: Isn't ExpandedArmor first-child of its parent(ExpandedSetPiece) and the last ExpandedCell the last-child? not sure why it needs spaces, but I guess I will start adding em from now on.

Comment: @LGSon it didn't work without the spaces, either ways I will research on em Thanks guys :) !!

Answer (score 0):

First add the border to each Div container and then add the border-radius

```
.ExpandedSetPiece{
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;}
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the code below where --border-radius is your wanted radius.

```css
:root {
  --border-radius: 10px;
}

.ExpandedArmor {
  border-radius: var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) 0 0;
}
.ExpandedCells:nth-child(3) {
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius);
```

Comment: that did work, but since there may be more elements added later due to javascript, It is not ideal to set it to nth-child(3) but setting it to last-child does not even work sadly Thanks for the help though :)